# MotoG 5.0.2 has wifi issues

Tags: android-5.0-lollipop, android-wifi, wifimanager

I have updated my MotoG to Android 5.0.2. But since then, I have been facing WiFi issues. My device does not detect the available wifi's. Some Wifi's, work when I change the channel, on my router. But these issues is not observed on my friends MotoG who has also upgraded to 5.0.2.

Please help me resolve this problem. Will factory reset solve the issue?

Comment: This is not a place for such posts - please try XDA forum.

Comment: @Tajchert actually there is https://android.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Im was also having the same issue . factory reset worked for me . If its not still not working roll back to kitkat. Lollipop 5.0.2 is not a stable for moto G. Lot of moto G user find it annoying because of many bugs.

Comment: check this out : http://forum.xda-developers.com/moto-g/general/android-lollipop-5-0-2-bugs-troubles-t3010332